# In html or in css I have a problem with the code

Tags: html, css

Good day or night. I have a problem maybe in the code html or css.
I do not know. Namely, I created a video tag after it wrote the div tag and wrote a comment in the h2 tag, but the text is not from the bottom, but from the side.

[The highlighted text should be at the bottom of the video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsxIj.png)

[And he is fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4t9cy.png)

Code css:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #555;
}

p {
  padding: 0 0 20px 0;
  line-height: 1.7em;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="search"] {
  color: #5d5d5d;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 8px;
}

input,
textarea {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border: solid 1px #f2f2f2;
}

h1,
h2 {
  font: normal 170% 'century gothic', arial;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
  padding: 15px 0 5px 0;
  color: #000;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 140%
}

a,
a:hover {
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: green;
}

ul {
  margin: 2px 0 22px 17px;
}

ul li {
  margin: 0 0 6px 0;
  padding: 0 0 4px 5px;
  line-height: #000;
}

.header {
  background-color: darkslateblue;
  height: 177px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  min-width: auto;
}

.mine,
.logo,
.menubar,
.site_content,
footer {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.logo {
  width: 880px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.logo h1,
.logo h2 {
  font: normal 300% 'century gothic', arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0 0 0 9px;
}

.logo_text h1,
h1 a,
h1 a:hover {
  padding: 22px 0 0 0;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.logo_text h2 {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding: 4px 0 0 0;
  color: #999;
}

.menubar {
  width: 950px;
  height: 46px;
}

ul.menu {
  float: right;
}

ul.menu li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 0 0 9px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 1px 2px 0 0;
}

ul.menu li a {
  font: normal 100% 'trebuchet ms', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 6px 35px 6px 28px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.menu li.selected a {
  color: #aeb002;
}

ul.menu li a:hover {
  color: #e4ec04;
}

hr {
  border: solid 2px black;
}

.site_content {
  width: 880px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
}

.sidebar_containter {
  float: right;
  width: 224px;
}

.sidebar {
  float: right;
  widows: 222px;
  padding: 5%;
  margin: 0 0 16px 0;
  border: solid 1px #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.btn {
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sidebar h2 {
  color: #136cb2;
}

.lables_passreg_text {
  font-size: 0.7em;
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-left: 2%;
}

.sitebar ul {
  margin: 0;
}

.sitebar ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

.sitebar .rating_sidebar {
  float: right;
}

.content {
  text-align: left;
  width: 620px;
  padding: 0 0 0 5px;
  float: left;
}

.content a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.film_block {
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.films_block img {
  border-radius: 1px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.posts .posts_content {
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.info_film_page {
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
}

.info_film_page .label {
  font-synthesis: 1.2em;
}

.info_film_page .value {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: black;
}

.information {
  color: black;
}

.hr_2 {}

.reviews_h {
  border-bottom: 100%;
  border-top: 100%;
}

.reviews {
  margin-top: 50%;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.reviews .review_name {
  bottom: 800px;
  background-color: #7258ad;
  color: white;
  padding: 1%;
}

footer {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: darkslateblue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 28px 0 5px 0;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  min-width: 900px;
}

footer a {
  color: #0fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

footer a:hover {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

footer p {
  padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="description" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="asset/css/style.css">
  <title>K.S-DxD</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="logo">
        <div class="logo_text">
          <h1><a href="/">KinoStar</a></h1>
          <h2>Кино - только для вас!</h2>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="menubar">
        <ul class="menu">
          <li class="selected"><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Фильмы</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Сериалы</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Рейтинг Фильмов</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="site_content">
      <div class="sidebar_containter">
        <div class="sidebar">
          <h2>Поиск</h2>
          <form method="post" action="#" id="search_form">
            <input type="search" name="search_field" placeholder="ваш запрос" />
            <input type="submit" class="btn" value="найти">
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar">
          <h2>Вход</h2>
          <form method="post" action="#" id="login">
            <input type="text" name="login_field" placeholder="логин" />
            <input type="password" name="password_field" placeholder="пароль" />
            <input type="submit" class="btn" value="вход" />
            <div class="lables_passreg_text">
              <span></span><a href="#">забыл пароль?</a><span></span>|<span></span><a href="#">регистрация</a><span></span>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar">
          <h2>Новости</h2>
          <span>31.10.2020</span>
          <p>Запуск сайта на тестовом хостинге.</p>
          <a href="#">Читать</a>
        </div>

        <div class="sidebar">
          <h2>Рейтинг фильмов</h2>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Наруто</a><span class="rating_sidebar"> 10</span></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dxd</a><span class="rating_sidebar"> 9.9</span></li>
            <li><a href="#">Убица гоблинов</a><span class="rating_sidebar"> 9.9</span></li>
            <li><a href="#">Моя геройская академия</a><span class="rating_sidebar"> 9.9</span></li>
            <li><a href="#">Шаман Кинг</a><span class="rating_sidebar"> 9.9</span></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="content">
        <h1>Демоны старшей школы/High School'DxD'</h1>

        <img src="asset/img/DxD.jpg" width="300" height="400">

        <div class="info_film_page">
          <h4><span class="label">Рейтин: </span><span class="value">9.9/10</span></h4>

          <h4><span class="label">Год: </span><span class="value">Весна 2018</span></h4>

          <h4><span class="label">Автор: </span><span class="value">Ісібумі Ітіей</span></h4><br>

          <h5>
            <spanc class="information">Иссэй Хёдо – довольной глупый и крайне озабоченный ученик старшего класса, который захотел оказаться в Академии Кудо, где основной контингент учащихся – девчонки. Но зря наивный юноша надеялся, что представительницы прекрасного пола станут
              бросаться ему на шею. Школьницы вообще не замечали парнишку. Но главный герой не сдавался, и вскоре удача ему улыбнулась, подарив свидание с юной красавицей – Юмой Амано. Разве мог мальчишка догадаться, что его ожидает не заветная романтика,
              а беспощадная расправа. Только неожиданно подоспевшая красотка из учебного заведения, являющаяся демоницей по имени Риас Гремори, избавляет шокированного паренька от смерти. Но теперь Хёдо приходится не только перевоплотиться в аналогичного
              демона, но еще и верного слугу спасительницы.Персонаж вступает в специальный клуб, где знакомится с прочими существами. Обретя необычные способности, старшеклассник наконец-то имеет возможность реализовать жизненную мечту и сформировать
              настоящий гарем. Впереди мечтательного султана ждет масса увлекательных приключений.</span>
          </h5>

        </div>
        <video class="video" width="600" height="400" controls>
                        <source src="asset/video/DxD triler.mp4" type="video/mp4" poster="asset/img/DxD.jpg">
                        </video>


      </div>

      <hr>
      <h2>Отзывы</h2>

      <div class="reviews">

        <div class="review_name">
          name
        </div>
        <div class="review_text">
          отзыв 12345.
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <footer>
    <p class="a_link">
      <a class="menubar" href="#">Главная</a> |
      <a href="#">Фильмы</a> |
      <a href="#">Сериалы</a> |
      <a href="#">Рейтинг</a> |
      <a href="#">Контакты</a>
    </p>
    <p>kn-st.com 2020</p>
  </footer>


</body>

</html>
```

Namely, the problem begins here:

```
            </div>
            <video class="video" width="600" height="400" controls>
            <source src="asset/video/DxD triler.mp4" type="video/mp4" 
             poster="asset/img/DxD.jpg">
            </video>
              
                
                </div >

            <hr>
            <h2>Отзывы</h2>

            <div class="reviews">
              
              <div class="review_name">
                name
              </div>
              <div class="review_text">
                отзыв 12345.
              </div>
```

Comment: Please post only relevant code for your issue

Comment: update your question, don't post code in comment. Nobody will see it

Comment: I update question

Comment: You close the `.content` element to early, with the `</div>` tag right after the video element. That means, the following `hr`, `h2` etc. are not part of this floated container element any more, so they are allowed to align next to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #555;
}

p {
  padding: 0 0 20px 0;
  line-height: 1.7em;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="search"] {
  color: #5d5d5d;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 8px;
}

input,
textarea {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border: solid 1px #f2f2f2;
}

h1,
h2 {
  font: normal 170% 'century gothic', arial;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
  padding: 15px 0 5px 0;
  color: #000;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 140%
}

a,
a:hover {
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: green;
}

ul {
  margin: 2px 0 22px 17px;
}

ul li {
  margin: 0 0 6px 0;
  padding: 0 0 4px 5px;
  line-height: #000;
}

.header {
  background-color: darkslateblue;
  height: 177px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  min-width: auto;
}

.mine,
.logo,
.menubar,
.site_content,
footer {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.logo {
  width: 880px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.logo h1,
.logo h2 {
  font: normal 300% 'century gothic', arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0 0 0 9px;
}

.logo_text h1,
h1 a,
h1 a:hover {
  padding: 22px 0 0 0;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.logo_text h2 {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding: 4px 0 0 0;
  color: #999;
}

.menubar {
  width: 950px;
  height: 46px;
}

ul.menu {
  float: right;
}

ul.menu li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 0 0 9px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 1px 2px 0 0;
}

ul.menu li a {
  font: normal 100% 'trebuchet ms', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 6px 35px 6px 28px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.menu li.selected a {
  color: #aeb002;
}

ul.menu li a:hover {
  color: #e4ec04;
}

hr {
  border: solid 2px black;
}

.site_content {
  width: 880px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
}

.sidebar_containter {
  float: right;
  width: 224px;
}

.sidebar {
  float: right;
  widows: 222px;
  padding: 5%;
  margin: 0 0 16px 0;
  border: solid 1px #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.btn {
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sidebar h2 {
  color: #136cb2;
}

.lables_passreg_text {
  font-size: 0.7em;
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-left: 2%;
}

.sitebar ul {
  margin: 0;
}

.sitebar ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

.sitebar .rating_sidebar {
  float: right;
}

.content {
  text-align: left;
  width: 620px;
  padding: 0 0 0 5px;
  float: left;
}

.content a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.film_block {
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.films_block img {
  border-radius: 1px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.posts .posts_content {
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.info_film_page {
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
}

.info_film_page .label {
  font-synthesis: 1.2em;
}

.info_film_page .value {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: black;
}

.information {
  color: black;
}

.hr_2 {}

.reviews_h {
  border-bottom: 100%;
  border-top: 100%;
}

.reviews {
  margin-top: ;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.reviews .review_name {
  bottom: 800px;
  background-color: #7258ad;
  color: white;
  padding: 1%;
}

footer {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: darkslateblue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 28px 0 5px 0;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  min-width: 900px;
}

footer a {
  color: #0fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

footer a:hover {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

footer p {
  padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="description" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="asset/css/style.css">
  <title>K.S-DxD</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="logo">
        <div class="logo_text">
          <h1><a href="/">KinoStar</a></h1>
          <h2>Кино - только для вас!</h2>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="menubar">
        <ul class="menu">
          <li class="selected"><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Фильмы</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Сериалы</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Рейтинг Фильмов</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="site_content">
      <div class="sidebar_containter">
        <div class="sidebar">
          <h2>Поиск</h2>
          <form method="post" action="#" id="search_form">
            <input type="search" name="search_field" placeholder="ваш запрос" />
            <input type="submit" class="btn" value="найти">
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar">
          <h2>Вход</h2>
          <form method="post" action="#" id="login">
            <input type="text" name="login_field" placeholder="логин" />
            <input type="password" name="password_field" placeholder="пароль" />
            <input type="submit" class="btn" value="вход" />
            <div class="lables_passreg_text">
              <span></span><a href="#">забыл пароль?</a><span></span>|<span></span><a href="#">регистрация</a><span></span>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar">
          <h2>Новости</h2>
          <span>31.10.2020</span>
          <p>Запуск сайта на тестовом хостинге.</p>
          <a href="#">Читать</a>
        </div>

        <div class="sidebar">
          <h2>Рейтинг фильмов</h2>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Наруто</a><span class="rating_sidebar"> 10</span></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dxd</a><span class="rating_sidebar"> 9.9</span></li>
            <li><a href="#">Убица гоблинов</a><span class="rating_sidebar"> 9.9</span></li>
            <li><a href="#">Моя геройская академия</a><span class="rating_sidebar"> 9.9</span></li>
            <li><a href="#">Шаман Кинг</a><span class="rating_sidebar"> 9.9</span></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="content">
        <h1>Демоны старшей школы/High School'DxD'</h1>

        <img src="asset/img/DxD.jpg" width="300" height="400">

        <div class="info_film_page">
          <h4><span class="label">Рейтин: </span><span class="value">9.9/10</span></h4>

          <h4><span class="label">Год: </span><span class="value">Весна 2018</span></h4>

          <h4><span class="label">Автор: </span><span class="value">Ісібумі Ітіей</span></h4><br>

          <h5>
            <spanc class="information">Иссэй Хёдо – довольной глупый и крайне озабоченный ученик старшего класса, который захотел оказаться в Академии Кудо, где основной контингент учащихся – девчонки. Но зря наивный юноша надеялся, что представительницы прекрасного пола станут
              бросаться ему на шею. Школьницы вообще не замечали парнишку. Но главный герой не сдавался, и вскоре удача ему улыбнулась, подарив свидание с юной красавицей – Юмой Амано. Разве мог мальчишка догадаться, что его ожидает не заветная романтика,
              а беспощадная расправа. Только неожиданно подоспевшая красотка из учебного заведения, являющаяся демоницей по имени Риас Гремори, избавляет шокированного паренька от смерти. Но теперь Хёдо приходится не только перевоплотиться в аналогичного
              демона, но еще и верного слугу спасительницы.Персонаж вступает в специальный клуб, где знакомится с прочими существами. Обретя необычные способности, старшеклассник наконец-то имеет возможность реализовать жизненную мечту и сформировать
              настоящий гарем. Впереди мечтательного султана ждет масса увлекательных приключений.</span>
          </h5>

        </div>
        <video class="video" width="600" height="400" controls>
                        <source src="asset/video/DxD triler.mp4" type="video/mp4" poster="asset/img/DxD.jpg">
                        </video>


      

      <hr>
      <h2>Отзывы</h2>

      <div class="reviews">

        <div class="review_name">
          name
        </div>
        <div class="review_text">
          отзыв 12345.
        </div>

      </div>
</div> <!-- close this div tag here -->

    </div>

  </div>

  <footer>
    <p class="a_link">
      <a class="menubar" href="#">Главная</a> |
      <a href="#">Фильмы</a> |
      <a href="#">Сериалы</a> |
      <a href="#">Рейтинг</a> |
      <a href="#">Контакты</a>
    </p>
    <p>kn-st.com 2020</p>
  </footer>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you just need to remove the div tag right before the <hr /> tag and close it after the reviews div tag, that's what's causing the problem. after doing it, you can remove the margin-top for your reviews div.

Comment: Please add the above comment into the answer if it is an explanation of how the code you provide resolve the issue